# Create PDF of predefined areas from multiple sheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm a real rookie in this world, but I hope you will bear with me.. :)

I'm working on a workbook where as a final result it is supposed to create an PDF overview. This should consist of information from areas in 3 sheets within the workbook.

From different threads I've constructed the below inserted code. Everytime I try to run this it gives me an error saying "Subscript out of range".

Any feedback would be much appreciated! :=)

```
Sub CreatePDF()

    Sheets("Sheet(1)").Select
    Range("B1:K27").Select
    Sheets("Sheet(7)").Select
    Range("A4:J37").Select
    Sheets("Sheet(3)").Select
    Range("A1:J24").Select

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet(1)", "Sheet(7)", "Sheet(3)")).Select
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\temp\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("Sheet(1)").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Array("Sheet(1)", "Sheet(7)", "Sheet(3)")
> ```

This should be either

```
Array(1, 7, 3) ' numeric indexes of sheets according to their tab positions
```

or

```
Array("Sheet1", "Sheet7", "Sheet3") ' exact names of sheets
```

Correct also `Sheets("Sheet(1)")`, should be either `Sheets("Sheet1")` or `Sheets(1)` according to your intent.